# mod_rewrite Add another rule

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I use this to forward all routing to index.php, If I would to rewrite the following:

http://localhost/folder/method/value

And that would be

http://localhost/folder/method/?f=value

How do I make it work?

Comment: Are you sure the first rule is working? Because `$1` isn't pre-defined.

Comment: Yes it does indeed, I am just looking to add another rule but I am confused how it should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [mod rewrite tage wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) and example 6.

For your specific case you could just *prepend* a rule like

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$  $1/$2/?f=$3 [L]
```

See also [Serverfault: Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as) to learn about rule ordering.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$  index.php?p=activate/$1 [L]

I tried this, it doesn't work.

Comment: And why would I care? What does this have to do with the answer I gave?

Comment: It should be this: RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ $1/?f=$2 [L], I tried to make your rule you gave me work, but it didn't, therefore, I wrote it.

Comment: Unlikely to work unless you read the links given. Don't repurpose your question in comments, btw.

Comment: Ah, it is the .* that stops me, If I change the .* to something like \w- it should work.